# Weighted Random Integers MATLAB

Tags: matlab, random

I am trying to generate random integers (either 0 or 1).  This code does this very well:

`randi([0 1],10000,1)`

The only problem is that `randi` obviously generates binomial distributions.  I need to be able to set a weighting to these numbers.  For example, I want 55% of the distribution to be 1 and the other 45% to be 0.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Weighted random numbers in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977497/weighted-random-numbers-in-matlab) – or [Generate Weighted Random Boolean Matrix in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370382/generate-weighted-random-boolean-matrix-in-matlab)

Comment: Even simpler than those answers in this case: `rand(10000,1)>0.45`.